# Model not binding correctly from a modal rendered partial

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am having a really werid issue my model is not binding to form correctly

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveCaseNotes", "MISObjects", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myForm", @name = "myForm" })) {  
<form id="myForm" asp-action="">
  <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Title" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title, string.Empty, new { @style = "color:red;" })

   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Summary)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Summary, new { @class = "form-control"})
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Summary, string.Empty, new { @style = "color:red;" })

   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes)
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes)

   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateReported)
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateReported, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker" } })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateReported)

   <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()" />

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</form>
}
```

This is my model

```
public class MISObjectNotes {
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public int MISObjectId { get; set; }
 public string Title { get; set; }
 public string Summary { get; set; }
 public string Notes { get; set; }
 public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
 public DateTime LastModifedDate { get; set; }
 public DateTime DateReported { get; set; }
 public DateTime DateActioned { get; set; }    
 public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
 public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
 public bool isAcitve { get; set; }
 public bool isDeleteted { get; set; }
}
```

This is my method but its not binding correctly from the above form btw the above form is behind1 render a partial inside a modal popup.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveCaseNotes(MISObjectNotes notes) {

MISObject tempObject = new MISObject();           
Int32.TryParse(HttpContext.Session.GetString("CaseId"),out int resultCaseId);
       
if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    notes.MISObjectId = resultCaseId;
    notes.isAcitve = true;
    notes.LastModifedDate = DateTime.Now;
    var test = notes.Notes;
    notes.LastModifiedBy = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Intitals");

    _context.Add(notes);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    tempObject = await _context.MISobject.Where(w=>w.Id== resultCaseId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

 }
 return View("Details",tempObject);
}
```

Comment: Do you see anything suspicious in browser console?

Comment: @viveknuna no when i come to debug the binding information is lost.

Comment: Hi @rogue39nin, Any updates about this case? Have you tried the solution that I shared?

Answer (score 0):

You added your model to _context:

```
_context.Add(notes);
```

so you should take it from _context, and not from _context.MISobject.

```
tempObject = await _context.Where(w=>w.Id== resultCaseId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

or did I missed something?

Comment: what is the model your view is based on?
You wrote your model is MISObjectNotes, but you return MISObject

Comment: Thats not the point the object is posting to the method which is of type notes MISObjectNotes but its this notes thats not getting filled cause its a  partial view

Comment: And please dont create a answer when u do not have enough contriubtion to comment its not the SO way

Answer (score 0):

> This is my method but its not binding correctly from the above form

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveCaseNotes(MISObjectNotes notes)
```

Based on the code you shared, we can find that you named action parameter with `"notes"`, and you defined a property `public string Notes { get; set; }` in model class `MISObjectNotes`, which cause model binding not working as expected.

To fix it, you can try to rename your action parameter, such as `"mISObjectNotes"` etc.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify why you use Form Tag Helper inside Html.BeginForm?